# AWS Zappa static files

Tags: amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, aws-lambda, static, zappa

I'm trying to create my first app with zappa. Everithing works fine, exept css style.

I installed also 'django_s3_storage', 'storages', and add them to my app.
Also I have the AWS settings:

```
S3_BUCKET = "<busket_name>"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = S3_BUCKET
STATIC_URL = "https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/" % S3_BUCKET
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % S3_BUCKET
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config("SERVER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", '')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('SERVER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', '')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('SERVER_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME', '')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-1'
```

What is wrong? The admin page still without css:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set AWS Bucket's permissions:
Set public permission and turn off 'Block all public access'
Set bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your_bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket Ownership

```
Permissions -> Ownership -> ACLs enabled
```

Run in terminal for collect static files

```
 python manage.py collectstatic
```

Restart your terminal and deploy zappa again for changes to take effect.